# Bonjour NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event speed (enabled WiFi and Bluetooth both)

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, wifi, bonjour, nsstream

I'm develpoing a network app using Bonjour service on iPhone devices.

My problem is that NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event speed is slow when i enable WiFi and Bluetooth both on my devices.

But strangely if i enable only one either WiFi or Bluetooth, NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event speed is fast normally.

Is it originally slow if enabled WiFi and Bluetooth both?

I have to consider this situations becuase any users can enable WiFi and Bluetooth both.

Thanks.

Comment: can you help me to understand how can we use Bonjur  to connect to non iOS devices

Comment: We've noticed that if you enable both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, Wi-Fi speed suffers. This probably has something to do with them using the same chip and antenna.

Comment: Are you still experiencing slowness under iOS 6.x?  Or did you develop along a different path and haven't pursued this?